# How to define `type` for `Electron` in typescript?

Tags: typescript, electron

When I write below code in Electron in TypeScript,

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;
```

I got this error: `Cannot find namespace 'Electron'.`.

I seems there is not namespace defined for the type`Electron`. I wonder where I can load this type definition. I have added these dependencies on my project:

```
"electron": "^5.0.2",
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to prefix your usage of `BrowserWindow`. You've already got the type imported, just use it directly.

```
import { BrowserWindow } from "electron";

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow;
```

Additionally, you don't need a separate `@types/electron` package for electron. The `electron` package is already typed.

Comment: I got this error `'BrowserWindow' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here` if I use BrowserWindow directly.

Comment: @ZhaoYi I updated this answer to use import instead of require.